# If $ab = ba$ in a ring of characteristic $p$, show that $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $ab = ba$ in a ring of characteristic $p$, show that $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p$.

So by the binomial theorem: $(a + b)^p =\sum\limits_{i=0}^p{ p\choose i} a^{p-i}b^i$.

Then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^p{ p\choose i} a^{p-i}b^i=a^p+\sum\limits_{i=1}^p{ p\choose i} a^{p-i}b^i =a^p+\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}{ p\choose i} a^{p-i}b^i\right) +b^p$.

so all that remains is to show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}{ p\choose i} a^{p-i}b^i = 0$ by making use of $p$ being prime and $ab=ba$, but I am not seeing how I can do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key result is that $p \choose i$ is a multiple of $p$ for $0 < i < p$. It is easy to prove.

Comment: I understand that $p\mid {p \choose i}$, I don't understand how this leads to ${p \choose i}a^{p-i}b^i = 0$

Comment: @Burgundy, in characteristic $p$, multiples of $p$ are equal to $0$.